# How to make thumbnail image from dailymotion video

Tags: android, video, dailymotion-api, video-thumbnails

I am showing number of dailymotion videos in ListView, i want to try to make thumbnail image from dailymotion video, but i am not getting any way to make thumb.

Have you any idea about it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{@id}?fields=thumbnail_medium_url,thumbnail_small_url,thumbnail_large_url
```

And you have following options and you can pass either one or all:
thumbnail_large_url (320px by 240px)
thumbnail_medium_url (160px by 120px)
thumbnail_small_url (80px by 60px)

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezrb?fields=thumbnail_medium_url,thumbnail_small_url,thumbnail_large_url

```
{
"thumbnail_medium_url": "http://s1.dmcdn.net/HRnTi/160x120-JQs.jpg",
"thumbnail_small_url": "http://s1.dmcdn.net/HRnTi/80x60-iBI.jpg",
"thumbnail_large_url": "http://s1.dmcdn.net/HRnTi/x240-oi8.jpg"
}
```

Comment: How to use this ?